# Test with ExpectedException fails when using PoweMock with PowerMockRule

Tags: junit, powermock

I am trying to work with PowerMock, over Mockito; as I loved the API's for whennew() and verifyprivate() but i have some problem when trying to run testsuites with Categories TestRunner in Junit.

For using default JUnit test runners, I created a TestCase and added **PowerMockRule as instance field with @Rule annotation**. While execution of tests worked like this, **ExpectedException** TestRule is not working when used in conjunction

Example Code

```
@PowerMockIgnore ("*")
@PrepareForTest (CustomizedSSHConnection.class)
public class TestExpectedExceptionRule {

    private Connection          connection;
    private ConnectionInfo      connectionInfo;
     @Rule
     public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule ();
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException    exception   = ExpectedException.none ();

    @Test
    public void testExcepitonWithPowerMockRule() {
        exception.expect (NullPointerException.class);
        exception.expectMessage ("Image is null");
        throw new NullPointerException ("Image is null");
    }
}
```

**Instead of using @Rule PowerMockRule if I use @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) this testcase will pass.**

One other observation is if I annotate PowerMockRule with @ClassRule this succeeds but some of the mocking methods throwing exceptions.

Comment: in what way is it not working? What is the behavior? It is not getting expected exceptions and failing the test because it expected the exception?

Comment: Expected output is to validate the Exception thrown with the message and return success; but instead it is throwing that exception raised as uncaught exception and reporting the test as errored out.

Comment: John, I was able to fix this, using expected attribute on the @Test annotation. But looking for some correct way of doing this using ExpectedException TestRule to validate the exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerMock creates a deep clone of the `TestExpectedExceptionRule` object. Because of this it is running the test with a new `ExpectedException` rule, but you're calling `exception.expect (NullPointerException.class)` on the original rule. Hence the test fails, because the clone of the `ExpectedException` rule doesn't expect an exception.

Nevertheless there are at least two solutions for your problem.

## RuleChain

Order the rules with JUnit's `RuleChain`. This needs some additional ugly code, but it works.

```java
private ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none ();
private PowerMockRule powerMockRule = new PowerMockRule();

@Rule
public TestRule ruleChain = RuleChain.outerRule(new TestRule() {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return powerMockRule.apply(base, null, description);
    }
}).around(exception);
```

## Fishbowl

If you are using Java 8 then you can replace the `ExpectedException` rule with the [Fishbowl](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/fishbowl) library.

```java
@Test
public void testExcepitonWithPowerMockRule() {
  Throwable exception = exceptionThrownBy(
    () -> throw new NullPointerException ("Image is null"));
  assertEquals(NullPointerException.class, exception.getClass());
  assertEquals("Image is null", exception.getMessage());
}
```

Without Java 8, you have to use an anonymous class.

```java
@Test
public void fooTest() {
  Throwable exception = exceptionThrownBy(new Statement() {
    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
      throw new NullPointerException ("Image is null");
    }
  });
  assertEquals(NullPointerException.class, exception.getClass());
  assertEquals("Image is null", exception.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful, and detailed answer Stefan, it worked great using Lambdas...

Comment: The RuleChain example in fact does not work at all, since PowermockRule is a  MethodRule and it really requires the method. Here's how I solved it: https://bitbucket.org/anydoby/gcloud-storage-emulator/src/master/src/main/java/com/anydoby/gcloud/MergedRule.java

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using the expected attribute in the `@Test` annotation. But the problem with this approach is that am unable to assert the exception message. Which is fine for me for now.

```
@PowerMockIgnore ("*")
@PrepareForTest (CustomizedSSHConnection.class)
public class TestExpectedExceptionRule {

    private Connection          connection;
    private ConnectionInfo      connectionInfo;
     @Rule
     public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule ();
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException    exception   = ExpectedException.none ();

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testExcepitonWithPowerMockRule() {
        throw new NullPointerException ("Image is null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a `PowerMockTestUtil` class that uses a `FunctionalInterface`.

Utility class:

```
/**
 * Utility class to provide some testing functionality that doesn't play well with Powermock out
 * of the box. For example, @Rule doesn't work well with Powermock.
 */
public class PowerMockTestUtil {

  public static void expectException(RunnableWithExceptions function, Class expectedClass, String expectedMessage) {
    try {
      function.run();
      fail("Test did not generate expected exception of type " + expectedClass.getSimpleName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      assertTrue(e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(expectedClass));
      assertEquals(expectedMessage, e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface RunnableWithExceptions<E extends Exception> {
    void run() throws E;
  }
}
```

Sample test:

```
  @Test
  public void testValidateMissingQuantityForNewItem() throws Exception {
    ...
    expectException(() -> catalogEntryAssociationImporter.validate(line),
        ImportValidationException.class,
        "Quantity is required for new associations");
  }
```